# Source files generation from WSDL using maven

Tags: java, web-services, maven, ant, wsdl

I am working on a migration project from ant to maven. The problem that I am facing is that, the package name which is generated from the WSDL is not including "www" which is present in xsd targetnamespace attribute.

Problem: http://pkg.example.com/sales/something is correctly generated as `com.example.pkg.sales.something`

whereas,http://www.example.com/sales/something is **incorrectly** generated as `com.example.sales.something`

Please let me know if any configuration changes are to be done other than changing the WSDL/import statements.

Any help is appreciated.

Updated.

Comment: I think that's normal. I don't think there's anything you can do.

Comment: @Tunaki. I have updated the question. The generated package name does not include "www"

Comment: Yes I understood. And I still think that's normal expected behaviour. Can't find a reference now but I would find it weird if `www` _were_ included.

Comment: If you're using CXF codegen you can pass it a JAX-WS binding file to customise the output, see here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html, `Example 1: Passing in a JAX-WS Binding file`